# Flash Memory Management

Tags: memory, arm, byte, flash-memory

I'm collecting data on an ARM Cortex M4 based evaluation kit in a remote location and would like to log the data to persistent memory for access later.

I would be logging roughly 300 bytes once every hour, and would want to come collect all the data with a PC after roughly 1 week of running.

I understand that I should attempt to minimize the number of writes to flash, but I don't have a great understanding of the best way to do this. I'm looking for a resource that would explain memory management techniques for this kind of situation.

I'm using the ADUCM350 which looks like it has 3 separate flash sections (128kB, 256kB, and a 16kB eeprom).

Comment: First you need to state what the flash memory is.  NOR or NAND and then MLC (multi-level NAND) or SLC.  NOR is the most flexible in what you may do for logging.  Also I would assume you have read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_file_system, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flash_file_systems#File_systems_optimized_for_flash_memory.2C_solid_state_media

Answer (score 0):

For logging applications the simplest and most effective wear leveling tactic is to treat the entire flash array as a giant ring buffer.

define an entry size to be some integer fraction of the smallest erasable flash unit. Say a sector is 4K(4096 bytes); let the entry size be 256.
This is to make all log entries be sector aligned and will allow you to erase any sector without cuting a log entry in half.

At boot, walk the memory and find the first empty entry. this is the 'write_pointer'

when a log entry is written, simply write it to write_pointer and increment write_pointer.
If write_pointer is on a sector boundary erase the sector at write_pointer to make room for the next write. essentially this guarantees that there is at least one empty log entry for you to find at boot and allows you to restore the write_pointer.

if you dedicate 128KBytes to the log entries and have an endurance of 20000 write/erase cycles. this should give you a total of 10240000 entries written before failure. or 1168 years of continuous logging...